# How to auto update child input jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm trying to use jquery to autoupdate an input field which is wrapped around a contenteditable div. There are multiple such divs that is generated by the backend code, and I would like each input to update only if its parent's div's contenteditable has been updated. The html looks something like this:

```
<div class="to-change" contenteditable="true">
    Text that can be edited
    <input name="autoupdate">
</div>
```

I have tried using the following jquery code:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
        $('.to-change').on("keyup", function() {
            var input = $(this).text()
            $('input:first-child').val(input)
        })
    });
</script>
```

The thing is when I try to change the text, every other such divs' input field will also be updated with the same text. How do I change the jquery code such that the input field will always take reference from its own parent div?

Thanks!

Comment: `$(this).find("input").val(input)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Select that element like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                console.log("ready!");
                $('.to-change').on("keyup", function () {
                    var input = $(this).text()
                    $('.to-change > :first-child').val(input);
                });
    })
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                console.log("ready!");
                $('.to-change').on("keyup", function () {
                    var input = $(this).text()
                    $('.to-change > input').val(input);
                });
    })
```

> ">" Used for selecting Direct childs of an Element, You can find More about this selector in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator